# Classifying boundary extrema and parametrizing the boundary of a function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to classify boundary extrema of a function.

For example, consider the function $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$ with $E = \{(x, y) \: | \: x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ given by $f(x, y) = x^2 - x + 2y^2$. I have seen multiple ways of parametrizing the boundary, but what confuses me is that those methods give different possible boundary extrema.

Furthermore, if I know the possible boundary extrema, I am having trouble figuring out wether those are actual extrema of $f$, and wether they are weak or strong.

For example, you can parametrize the boundary by using that on the boundary, you have $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so $y^2 = 1 - x^2$, so then $g(x) = x^2 - x + 2(1 - x^2) = -x^2 - x + 2$ parametrizes the boundary. Then the derivative is zero at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$, so $f$ possibly has extrema at $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ and $(-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$.

Parametrizing the boundary using $g(t) = f(\cos(t), \sin(t)) = -\cos(t) + \sin^2(t)$ however gives more extrema, since then $g'(t) = \sin(t)(1 + 2\cos(t))$, which is zero for $t \in \{0, \pi, \frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3} \}$, giving additional possible boundary extrema $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$, and also the two from before.

Even more confusing is $h : E \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 +x$, since then parametrizing using $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ gives zero possible boundary extrema, because the derivative of $g(x) = 1 + x$ is zero nowhere. So what is going on here? Why don't both ways of parametrizing the boundary work?

Thanks for reading, any amount of help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that when you do $y^2=1-x^2\implies f(x,y)=-x^2-x+2$, the values that $x$ can take belong to $[-1,1]$. So, it is not enough to see the points at which the derivative is $0$; you also have to check what happens at the extreme points of the interval $[-1,1]$, wich are $\pm1$.

Comment: Ah right ofcourse, thanks! But I still don't know how to figure out if the 4 points we have now are extrema of $f$, especially since they live on the boundary, so looking at the derivative of $f$ on those points doesn't work... can you maybe help me with this too?

Comment: You have these four points: $\left(-\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$ and $(\pm1,0)$. And you can check that $f\left(-\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)=\frac94$, that $f(1,0)=0$, and that $f(-1,0)=2$. So, maximum is $\frac94$, which is attained at $\left(-\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$, and the minimum is $0$, which is attained at $(1,0)$.

Comment: I should have been clearer, I want to know if the boundary extrema are also extrema of $f$ on $E$, not just on the boundary. 

I did figure out a little bit more though, by setting the derivative to 0 I found the only interior extrema is ($\frac{1}{2}$, 0), and the Hessian gives that this is a strong minimum. Since $E$ is compact, but there are no interior maxima, it follows that $\left(- \frac{1}{2}, \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right)$ are absolute strong maximum.

Then the only thing I do not know yet is wether the points $(\pm 1, 0)$ are local minima of $f$, and wether they're strong/weak.

Comment: None of the points $(\pm1,0)$ is a local minimum, since the map $x\mapsto f(x,0)=x^2-x$ actually *decreases* near $-1$ and *increases* near $1$.